# How can i sleep my arduino for 12 minutes?

Tags: c++, arduino, sensors

So i have had produced this code, but i cannot seem to sleep my Arduino Uno for my desired time. I need the Arduino Uno to sleep for 12 minutes, wake up and take readings after 3 minutes (warm up time for my sensors), then take readings for 5 minutes. I have got the wake up and reading times correct, just can't seem to get sleep time correct.

I have managed to get it to around 12 minutes sleep time with `const int time_interval = 2000 ;` as seen below, but it changes every time it sleeps, seems to be increasing by one minute every time..

Can anyone help? These are the snippets of code that conrol the time, with full code after:

```
const unsigned long eventInterval = (1000UL*60*3);   //Assign the time in millis for event interval (every 15 minutes) 
unsigned long startTime =  millis()+ eventInterval;
unsigned long readingInterval= (1000UL*60*5);             //Assign the time in millis for reading (every 5 minutes) 

//SD stack select
const int chipSelect = 10;
//const int pingPin = 7;


//RTC Module Global Variables
const int time_interval = 2000 ;  // Sets the wakeup interval in minutes.
```

....and.....

```
    /* This is the event */
 if ((long)(millis()-startTime)>=0) {


  delay(10);
  unsigned long i=millis();
  while ((long)((i+readingInterval)-millis())>=0){
  //Get the values of the sensors
  GetRTC_Readings();
  GetVOC_Readings();
  GetPM_Readings();
  GetBME_Readings();
  delay (5000); // to give time for PMS to take readings?

  // Store the three sensor values to the SD card.
  print2SD();
  delay(5000);
  } 
   
  digitalWrite(indicator,HIGH);
  delay(2000); 
  digitalWrite(indicator,LOW);
  Serial.println("Going to sleep for 12 minutes");
  digitalWrite(Relay_pin,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Relay_pin2,LOW);
 
  delay(100);
  for(int i = 0; i<= 6*time_interval; i++) //this is sleeping arduino for 12 minutes
  {
  LowPower.idle(SLEEP_8S, ADC_OFF, TIMER2_OFF, TIMER1_OFF, TIMER0_OFF,SPI_OFF, USART0_OFF, TWI_OFF);
  }
  delay(1000);
  startTime = millis()+ eventInterval; //this is what affects the time
  Serial.println("Arduino: Hey I just Woke up");
  Serial.println("");
  delay(1000);
  
 }
}
```

Comment: That is a lot of code to read through! Can you provide a minimal example instead (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Why does your comment say `//this is sleeping arduino for 24 seconds` when the code at that point sleeps arduino for 12 minutes minus 24 seconds? And why minus 24 seconds? Why loop `6 * 12` and not loop `(60 * 12) / 8` times for a sleep of (approx.) 12 minutes?

Comment: Hey SamBob, I edited the code to show just the important bits. I had help with this code so far and i am still a beginner so still trying to understand it. The 'sleep for 24 seconds' was a comment i forgot to take out from the test, my bad.

Comment: Where and how would you place this loop of (60 * 12) and how would you make it loop 8 times for a sleep of (approx.) 12 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

You should **always** update the comments you have in your code when you are changing it.

For the solution you should change the for loop that puts your board to idle mode.
The code: `LowPower.idle(SLEEP_8S, ADC_OFF, TIMER2_OFF, TIMER1_OFF, TIMER0_OFF,SPI_OFF, USART0_OFF, TWI_OFF);` Will put your board to idle for 8 seconds + the time the board needs to wake up. So you should change the for loop time_interval. From the code that you posted you are using the time_interval only for the for loop so instead of calculating it inside of it you can set it to 12 minutes on initialization:  `const int time_interval = 12 * 60;  // 12 minute wake up interval in seconds .`

The start of the for loop would then be like that: `for(int i = 0; i < time_interval / 8; i++)`
The division by 8 could be done in the initialization, but it is more clear to have it in for loop that is putting the board to idle for 8s each round.

If your timings need to be more precise you need to take into account wake-up times and delays that you have in your code.